# How to set Content-Type on HttpURLConnection in Android?

Tags: android

Do you know how to set Content-Type on HttpURLConnection?

Please advise

Thanx

Comment: -1, You did not show any reasearch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use HttPost if you can:

```
 HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost( "url" );
 httpost.addHeader( "Content-Type", "text/plain" );
```